# Symfony 2 getter returns error: {"__initializer__":{},"__cloner__":{},"__isInitialized__":false}

Tags: php, json, symfony, getter

I'm having a problem with a getter created by Symfony 2 while trying to generate a JSON. The getter is getNcomptador(), which returns a kind of an error.

Function called to create the JSON:

```
public function llistatLecturesAction($db){

    $sessio = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->get('aquagest');

    $arrayAuxiliar = array();

    $lecturesRepository = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AquagestLecturesBundle:Lectura', 'aquagest_'.$db);
    $lectures = $lecturesRepository->findBy(array(),array('id'=>'ASC'));

    $elmarray = array();

    foreach ($lectures as $lectura) {
        $aux['id'] = $lectura->getId();
        $aux['any'] = $lectura->getLecany();
        $aux['trimestre'] = $lectura->getTrimestre();
        $aux['lectura'] = $lectura->getLectura();
        $aux['nComptador'] = $lectura->getNcomptador();
        //if($lectura->getId() == 1) $prova = $lectura->getNcomptador();

        array_push($elmarray, $aux);
        $i++;
    }

    return new JsonResponse($elmarray);

}
```

Lectura Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Aquagest\LecturesBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Lectura
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Aquagest\LecturesBundle\Repository\LecturaRepository")
 */
class Lectura
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="data", type="datetime")
 */
private $data;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="trimestre", type="integer")
 */
private $trimestre;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lecany", type="integer")
 */
private $lecany;

/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lectura", type="float")
 */
private $lectura;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Aquagest\SubministramentsBundle\Entity\ComptadorSubministrament", inversedBy="lectures")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lectura_ncomptador", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
protected $ncomptador;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="fotografia", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $fotografia = "";

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="incidencia", type="boolean")
 */
private $incidencia;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="estacional", type="boolean")
 */
private $estacional;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="anomalia", type="boolean")
 */
private $anomalia;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="panterior", type="boolean")
 */
private $panterior;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="motiuIncidencia", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $motiuIncidencia = "";

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tipus", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $tipus;

/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="consum", type="float")
 */
private $consum;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="canviComptador", type="boolean", options={"default"=false})
 */
private $canviComptador = false;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="voltaComptador", type="boolean", options={"default"=false})
 */
private $voltaComptador = false;

/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="numDigits", type="float", nullable=true, options={"default"=null})
 */
private $numDigits = null;

/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lecturaInicial", type="float", nullable=true, options={"default"=null})
 */
private $lecturaInicial = null;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="regularitzacio", type="boolean", options={"default"=false})
 */
private $regularitzacio = false;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Aquagest\AlertesabastamentBundle\Entity\RegistreAlertaAbastament", mappedBy="lecturaSubministrament")
 */
protected $registreAlertes;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Aquagest\ComptabilitatBundle\Entity\FacturaLectura", inversedBy="lectura")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lectura_factura", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
protected $factura;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set data
 *
 * @param \DateTime $data
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function setData($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get data
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getData()
{
    return $this->data;
}

/**
 * Set trimestre
 *
 * @param integer $trimestre
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function setTrimestre($trimestre)
{
    $this->trimestre = $trimestre;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get trimestre
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getTrimestre()
{
    return $this->trimestre;
}

/**
 * Set lecany
 *
 * @param integer $lecany
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function setLecany($lecany)
{
    $this->lecany = $lecany;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get lecany
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getLecany()
{
    return $this->lecany;
}

/**
 * Set lectura
 *
 * @param float $lectura
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function setLectura($lectura)
{
    $this->lectura = $lectura;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get lectura
 *
 * @return float 
 */
public function getLectura()
{
    return $this->lectura;
}

/**
 * Set ncomptador
 *
 * @param \Aquagest\SubministramentsBundle\Entity\ComptadorSubministrament $ncomptador
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function setNcomptador(\Aquagest\SubministramentsBundle\Entity\ComptadorSubministrament $ncomptador = null)
{
    $this->ncomptador = $ncomptador;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get ncomptador
 *
 * @return \Aquagest\SubministramentsBundle\Entity\ComptadorSubministrament 
 */
public function getNcomptador()
{
    return $this->ncomptador;
}

/**
 * Set fotografia
 *
 * @param string $fotografia
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function setFotografia($fotografia)
{
    $this->fotografia = $fotografia;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get fotografia
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getFotografia()
{
    return $this->fotografia;
}

/**
 * Set incidencia
 *
 * @param boolean $incidencia
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function setIncidencia($incidencia)
{
    $this->incidencia = $incidencia;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get incidencia
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getIncidencia()
{
    return $this->incidencia;
}

/**
 * Set estacional
 *
 * @param boolean $estacional
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function setEstacional($estacional)
{
    $this->estacional = $estacional;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get estacional
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getEstacional()
{
    return $this->estacional;
}

/**
 * Set anomalia
 *
 * @param boolean $anomalia
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function setAnomalia($anomalia)
{
    $this->anomalia = $anomalia;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get anomalia
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getAnomalia()
{
    return $this->anomalia;
}

/**
 * Set panterior
 *
 * @param boolean $panterior
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function setPanterior($panterior)
{
    $this->panterior = $panterior;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get panterior
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getPanterior()
{
    return $this->panterior;
}

/**
 * Set motiuIncidencia
 *
 * @param string $motiuIncidencia
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function setMotiuIncidencia($motiuIncidencia)
{
    $this->motiuIncidencia = $motiuIncidencia;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get motiuIncidencia
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getMotiuIncidencia()
{
    return $this->motiuIncidencia;
}

/**
 * Set tipus
 *
 * @param string $tipus
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function setTipus($tipus)
{
    $this->tipus = $tipus;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tipus
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTipus()
{
    return $this->tipus;
}

/**
 * Set consum
 *
 * @param float $consum
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function setConsum($consum)
{
    $this->consum = $consum;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get consum
 *
 * @return float 
 */
public function getConsum()
{
    return $this->consum;
}

/**
 * Funció que crea la carpeta de la lectura
 * @return [type] [description]
 */
public function createFolder($plataforma){
    try{
        umask(0000);
        mkdir("./uploads/".$plataforma."/lectures/lectura_".$this->id);
        return true;
    }catch(Exception $e){
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Funció que elimina la carpeta de la lectura
 * @return [type] [description]
 */
public function removeFolder($plataforma){
    try{
        umask(0000);
        $dir = "./uploads/".$plataforma."/lectures/lectura_".$this->id;
        shell_exec("rm -Rf ".$dir);
        return true;
    }catch(Exception $e){
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Set canviComptador
 *
 * @param boolean $canviComptador
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function setCanviComptador($canviComptador)
{
    $this->canviComptador = $canviComptador;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get canviComptador
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getCanviComptador()
{
    return $this->canviComptador;
}

/**
 * Set voltaComptador
 *
 * @param boolean $voltaComptador
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function setVoltaComptador($voltaComptador)
{
    $this->voltaComptador = $voltaComptador;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get voltaComptador
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getVoltaComptador()
{
    return $this->voltaComptador;
}

/**
 * Set numDigits
 *
 * @param float $numDigits
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function setNumDigits($numDigits)
{
    $this->numDigits = $numDigits;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get numDigits
 *
 * @return float 
 */
public function getNumDigits()
{
    return $this->numDigits;
}

/**
 * Set lecturaInicial
 *
 * @param float $lecturaInicial
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function setLecturaInicial($lecturaInicial)
{
    $this->lecturaInicial = $lecturaInicial;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get lecturaInicial
 *
 * @return float 
 */
public function getLecturaInicial()
{
    return $this->lecturaInicial;
}

/**
 * Set regularitzacio
 *
 * @param boolean $regularitzacio
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function setRegularitzacio($regularitzacio)
{
    $this->regularitzacio = $regularitzacio;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get regularitzacio
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getRegularitzacio()
{
    return $this->regularitzacio;
}

public function rotarImatge($direccio, $plataforma){

    if($direccio == 'esquerra'){
        shell_exec("convert -rotate -90 ./uploads/".$plataforma."/lectures/lectura_".$this->id."/'".$this->fotografia."' ./uploads/".$plataforma."/lectures/lectura_".$this->id."/'".$this->fotografia."'");
    }else{
        shell_exec("convert -rotate 90 ./uploads/".$plataforma."/lectures/lectura_".$this->id."/'".$this->fotografia."' ./uploads/".$plataforma."/lectures/lectura_".$this->id."/'".$this->fotografia."'");
    }
}
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->registreAlertes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add registreAlertes
 *
 * @param \Aquagest\AlertesabastamentBundle\Entity\RegistreAlertaAbastament $registreAlertes
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function addRegistreAlerte(\Aquagest\AlertesabastamentBundle\Entity\RegistreAlertaAbastament $registreAlertes)
{
    $this->registreAlertes[] = $registreAlertes;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove registreAlertes
 *
 * @param \Aquagest\AlertesabastamentBundle\Entity\RegistreAlertaAbastament $registreAlertes
 */
public function removeRegistreAlerte(\Aquagest\AlertesabastamentBundle\Entity\RegistreAlertaAbastament $registreAlertes)
{
    $this->registreAlertes->removeElement($registreAlertes);
}

/**
 * Get registreAlertes
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getRegistreAlertes()
{
    return $this->registreAlertes;
}

/**
 * Add factures
 *
 * @param \Aquagest\ComptabilitatBundle\Entity\FacturaLectura $factures
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function addFacture(\Aquagest\ComptabilitatBundle\Entity\FacturaLectura $factures)
{
    $this->factures[] = $factures;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove factures
 *
 * @param \Aquagest\ComptabilitatBundle\Entity\FacturaLectura $factures
 */
public function removeFacture(\Aquagest\ComptabilitatBundle\Entity\FacturaLectura $factures)
{
    $this->factures->removeElement($factures);
}

/**
 * Get factures
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getFactures()
{
    return $this->factures;
}

/**
 * Set factura
 *
 * @param \Aquagest\ComptabilitatBundle\Entity\FacturaLectura $factura
 * @return Lectura
 */
public function setFactura(\Aquagest\ComptabilitatBundle\Entity\FacturaLectura $factura = null)
{
    $this->factura = $factura;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get factura
 *
 * @return \Aquagest\ComptabilitatBundle\Entity\FacturaLectura 
 */
public function getFactura()
{
    return $this->factura;
}
}
```

JSON display

```
[{"id":12,"any":2014,"trimestre":1,"lectura":25,"nComptador":{"__initializer__":{},"__cloner__":{},"__isInitialized__":false}},{"id":13,"any":2014,"trimestre":2,"lectura":20,"nComptador":{"__initializer__":{},"__cloner__":{},"__isInitialized__":false}},{"id":14,"any":2014,"trimestre":3,"lectura":10,"nComptador":{"__initializer__":{},"__cloner__":{},"__isInitialized__":false}},{"id":15,"any":2014,"trimestre":4,"lectura":5,"nComptador":{"__initializer__":{},"__cloner__":{},"__isInitialized__":false}},{"id":20,"any":2015,"trimestre":1,"lectura":4,"nComptador":{"__initializer__":{},"__cloner__":{},"__isInitialized__":false}},{"id":21,"any":2015,"trimestre":2,"lectura":3,"nComptador":{"__initializer__":{},"__cloner__":{},"__isInitialized__":false}},{"id":22,"any":2015,"trimestre":4,"lectura":2,"nComptador":{"__initializer__":{},"__cloner__":{},"__isInitialized__":false}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fetch object of Lecture entity, you can try this

```
 $lectures = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AquagestLecturesBundle:Lectura')
        ->createQueryBuilder('l')
    ->join('l.ncomptador','n')
    ->select('l','n')->orderBy('l.id')->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
return jsonResponse($lectures);
```

Comment: I've tried it, exactly as written, but it gives an error `Attempted to call function "jsonResponse" from namespace "**dir of the folder**".`, so i added  `new` between `return` and `jsonResponse($lectures);`.
Now the json displays an empty array, just like `[]`

Comment: I've solved the problem by creating an auxiliar property to `Lectura` entity, I created a`$ncomptadorAux` which directly takes the value from the database, rather than `$ncomptador` which is treated as a new object because it's a foreign key in the database.

Comment: JsonResponse is a Response class under HTTPFoundation Component. you should add
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse

Comment: I already had `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;` before I posted the question.

I forgot to say that I already made a functional JSON by deleting `$aux['nComptador'] = $lectura->getNcomptador();`, so the problem is just there.